# Got error in 1602 LCD

Tags: lcd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mega 2560 and LCD 1602 got error messages when upload](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36876/mega-2560-and-lcd-1602-got-error-messages-when-upload)

I just received the Sainsmart 1602 LCD and when I was trying to get it work, tried the hello world sketch, I got this error:
/*avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
What seems to be the problem?