# Mega 2560 and LCD 1602 got error messages when upload

Tags: arduino

I am talking about [Mega 2560 and LCD 1602](http://www.sainsmart.com/evaluation-board/sainsmart-mega2560-1602-lcd-keypad-shield-kit-for-atmel-atmega8u2-avr.html)

When I tried uploading the program, it just gave me these error messages:

avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer

the arduino isn't lighting up or anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like an error with the LCD or the sketch. The error message means that your Arduino IDE (or rather the underlying avrdude program) cannot connect to the Arduino board. So check you setting and your connections to the board. If this error persist, try to get more information about it, and then ask a more targeted question (which board do you have, how is it connected, can you program it at all, which IDE version do you use, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

You already have similar open questions. Do some research before posting, you'll find things like:

[Arduino Mega2560 can't be programmed via USB](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=115010.0)

Which suggests a work around and how to provide more advanced debugging info.

Comment: If there are questions very similar to this one you should flag it as "exact duplicate", referring to the duplicate, instead of answering.

Comment: @stevenvh I believe I did this, but they lacked the advice/link I provided.

Comment: A link on its own is not considered an answer. If you instead detail advice here it can be valuable. Telling people to do research is counterproductive, we want to be the source.